# Allocating space for array

Tags: mips

For a project, I need to allocate space for an array of half-words which is supplied by the user. Thus far, I have:

```
.data
get_size: .asciiz "Enter array size: "
myArray: .space $s0

.text
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, get_size
syscall # Print get size message

li  $v0, 5
syscall # Put array size into $v0

mul $s0, $v0, 2 # Multiply $v0 by element size to reserve memory space
```

However, this throws an error at the myArray .space $s0 line. Whenever I hardcode in a value after .space the program works fine, but I specially need to calculate the space to allocate based on whatever the user give me.

Comment: Just use, C, not this strange language no one ever heard of

Comment: Use system call 9 to allocate memory dynamically.